# Can firebase functions .secret.local specify kebab case environment variable names?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Secret manager can specify kebab case secret name, but I meet the error

> functions: Failed to read local secrets file /work/dist/.secret.local: Invalid dotenv file, error on lines: project-bucket-url="gs://demo-project.appspot.com"

with /work/dist/.secret.local contains

```
project-bucket-url="gs://demo-project.appspot.com"
```

though defineSecret("project-bucket-url") works with kebab case secret name in production.
How can we overwrite the defined value in emulator environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the error message says that file is a "[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)" file.  That has a specific format.  [From what I can see](https://hexdocs.pm/dotenvy/dotenv-file-format.html#variable-names), hyphens are not allowed in dotenv key names.

> For the sake of portability (and sanity), environment variable names must consist solely of letters, digits, and the underscore ( _ ) and must not begin with a digit. In regex-speak, the names must match the following pattern:
>
> ```
> [a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
> ```

That's probably because dotenv was invented as a method to store environment variables, which typically use underscore as a word separator, and also all caps.

You should consider changing the names to something more conventional and supported by dotenv.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Following your answer, I decided to use .env.local with variables only used  in local development to bypass to read secret value, because our secret names are too many and kept by terraform and local environment variables for dev is not sensitive. I hope .secret.env will accept  characters at least secret manager allows by the way to accept json format, so on.